# String input was not in a correct format with a negative float - C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a basic xml file in C#. Here's the deserializing code :

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("Plugins/LSPDFR/LSPSAddonCallouts.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Custom.CustomMission>),
              new XmlRootAttribute("CustomMissions"));
            customMissions.AddRange((List<Custom.CustomMission>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }
```

but I get this error when running the code :

```
Errore nel documento XML (9, 4).   in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
[11/04/2017 10:56:51.346] in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
        [11/04/2017 10:56:51.347] System.FormatException: Formato della stringa di input non corretto.
    [11/04/2017 10:56:51.347] in System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
    [11/04/2017 10:56:51.347] in System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToSingle(String s)
    [11/04/2017 10:56:51.348] in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read2_CustomMission(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
    [11/04/2017 10:56:51.348] in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read3_CustomMissions()
```

The line which causes the problem in my xml file is this line :

```
<startposprotaY>-726.2017f</startposprotaY>
```

There are other float numbers ahead of this line that were deserialized without any problem, but this one won't. The only difference with the other floats is that this is the only negative float of the xml file, the other ones are positive.

Comment: Are you sure it's to do with being negative and not the decimal separator? If your culture uses `,` instead of `.` this would fail.

Comment: First of the `XmlSerializer` needs a descent root-tag. You have a `List<T>, which is not a valud one. You should thus wrap the list into your own type which you can then serialize. Anyway without your class´ code it´s hard to guess what´s going on.

Comment: The "terminal" `f` is illegal. `XmlConvert.ToSingle("1234f")` will throw an exception.